# How to use Yanmai SF-777 condenser microphone with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, microphone

I bought a Yanmai SF-777 condenser microphone, and attached it's USB cable into my Z440 HP Workstation running Ubuntu 20.04 OS. The microphone appears as input device in the Sound section of the settings, however, when trying to test it, the orange bar beneath doesn't reflect receiving any sound. Any ideas?